# can not find module @react-native-firebase/auth

Tags: firebase, react-native

I've been trying to use firebase auth with react native. I've gone through react native firebase doc and installed @react-native-firebase/app but when i trying to import @react-native-firebase/auth it's throwing an error "This module does not exist". Do i need to install @react-native-firebase/auth separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you do. The basic firebase package only allows you to access some basic functions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've wasted my 2 hours just to figured this out. Even they haven't mentioned it anywhere in the docs

Comment: I don't really like firebase's documentation either :P
No problems, HF !
(Btw, it's the same for every firebase package i think. Analytics, Messaging, ...)